# I am trying to get this order of coffee correct and get the final order. The logic is a bit tricky

Tags: javascript

```
enter code here
```

//  I am trying to get the final order if by avoiding the wrong size,creamer and sweetener if //ok  then go to the right size or options. But this did not work

```
`enter code here`
  function verifyCoffeeOrder (size, creamer, sweetener) {
  if (!size) {
    return "I'm sorry, that is not a valid size.";
  } else if ( size === 'small' || size === 'large') {
    return size; 
  } else {
    if ( !creamer) {
      return 'We only have milk or half and half!';
    } else if ( creamer === 'milk' || creamer === 'half and half') {
      return creamer;
    } else {
      if ( !sweetener) {
        return 'We don\'t have that sweetener.';
      } else if ( sweetener === 'sugar' || sweetener === 'splenda'){
        return sweetener;
      } else {
        return "A" + size +"cup of coffee with "+ creamer +'and'+ sweetener+'.';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: hi what input failed to work, is there an expected output?

Comment: please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: dont wrap `creamer and sweetener' into the `else block` of `if (!size)`. It will be like this: `if (!size) {/*...do something*/} else { size = '?'};if (!creamer) {/*...do something*/} else { creamer= '?'}; if (!sweetener) {/*...do something*/} else { sweetener= '?'}; return {size, creamer, sweetener};`

Comment: If `size` is `'small'` or `'large'` it returns the `size`. See the issue there?

Answer (score 1):

When you `return` from a function, the execution of that function stops.

So you need to only return when there is an error, otherwise continue with the next part of the code.

```js
function verifyCoffeeOrder(size, creamer, sweetener) {
  // if size is not valid return a relevant error
  if (size !== 'small' && size !== 'large') {
    return "I'm sorry, that is not a valid size.";
  }
  // if we get here, then size is valid
  // if creamer is not valid return a relevant error
  if (creamer !== 'milk' && creamer !== 'half and half') {
    return 'We only have milk or half and half!';
  }
  // if we get here, then both size and creamer are valid
  // if sweetener is not valid return a relevant error
  if (sweetener !== 'sugar' && sweetener !== 'splenda') {
    return 'We don\'t have that sweetener.';
  }
  // if we get here all three are valid
  // return order text
  return "A " + size + " cup of coffee with " + creamer + ' and ' + sweetener + '.';
}

console.log(verifyCoffeeOrder());
console.log(verifyCoffeeOrder('small'));
console.log(verifyCoffeeOrder('large','milk'));
console.log(verifyCoffeeOrder('small','half and half','splenda'));
```